# Cannot convert string to system.io

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my file stream to read whatever text file the user selects. The file path will be in a text box after they select it.

I want to use this file path so that my streamreader knows what file to read.

"Stream fileStream = FilePath.Text;" is not working.

```
public void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            {


                List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                string[] finalArray;

                Stream fileStream = FilePath.Text;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    // We read the file then we split it.
                    string lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] splittedArray = lines.Split(',');

                    // We will check here if any of the strings is empty (or just whitespace).
                    foreach (string currentString in splittedArray)
                    {
                        if (currentString.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            // If the string is not empty then we add to our temporary list.
                            temp.Add(currentString);
                        }
                    }

                    // We have our splitted strings in temp List.
                    // If you need an array instead of List, you can use ToArray().
                    finalArray = temp.ToArray();
 }
}
```

I get the error can't convert string to system.io.

How can I get the streamreader to read the chosen file from the "FilePath" text box

Comment: `new StreamReader(FilePath.Text)` ?

Comment: Unless you really want to use a stream, why not use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) - _"Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file."_ or [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) - _"Opens a text file, reads all the text in the file into a string, and then closes the file."_

Comment: This is the problem: `Stream fileStream = FilePath.Text;`, `FilePath.Text` is presumably a `string`, and you can't convert the string to `Stream`. Instead, *open* the stream using the string, or use one of the comments or answer(s) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilePath.Text` returns a string which is the location of the file on the drive

the below code would work

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath.Text))
{
    // We read the file then we split it.
    string lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] splittedArray = lines.Split(',');

    // We will check here if any of the strings is empty (or just whitespace).
    foreach (string currentString in splittedArray)
    {
        if (currentString.Trim() != "")
        {
            // If the string is not empty then we add to our temporary list.
            temp.Add(currentString);
        }
    }

    // We have our splitted strings in temp List.
    // If you need an array instead of List, you can use ToArray().
    finalArray = temp.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_) of the `StreamReader` constructor which accepts the path

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath.Text))
```